# TextInput clears text when secureTextEntry is true

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-textinput

Hello I am using TextInput of react native and there is an eye option to view or hide password. When I set secureTextEntry to true and type another character in input it clears all previous data and just types the character.

Here is my code :

```
<TextInput
 ref={ref => this._password = ref}
 style={[style.greyTextStyle, style.textinputStyle]}
 placeholder={strings.PASSWORD}
 secureTextEntry={this.state.securepass}
 placeholderTextColor={color.GREY_TEXT_COLOR}
 underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
 value={this.state.password}
 onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ password: text }) }} />
```

On clicking on eye btn I toggle secure text entry

```
showPassword() {
 this.setState({ securepass: !this.state.securepass });
 if (this.state.securepass == false) {
  this.setState({ passIcon: 'eye' })
 } else {
  this.setState({ passIcon: 'eye-off' })
 }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Same issue , you fixed it ?

Comment: @David, No. I have not found a viable option yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the iOS native behavior. Please check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9148 and this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12939. You can try save the value before toggling show/hide password and set again after that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that Osiel Lima is correct, and this is indeed the intended behavior for iOS. It's very poorly designed behavior, IMHO, but it does seem to be fairly consistent across various apps on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

setting property `clearTextOnFocus` to false in your textInput might help

```
<TextInput
 clearTextOnFocus={false}
 ref={ref => this._password = ref}
 style={[style.greyTextStyle, style.textinputStyle]}
 placeholder={strings.PASSWORD}
 secureTextEntry={this.state.securepass}
 placeholderTextColor={color.GREY_TEXT_COLOR}
 underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
 value={this.state.password}
 onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ password: text }) }} />
```